# Open RAR file and get folder inside the archive

Tags: c#, rar

I have lots of `.rar` files with lots of folders inside them. I want to read the `.rar` files' names and enter them to get the folders' names, then enter the folders. I don't want to extract the `.rar` files.

Comment: Entering rar files means you have to extract them at least info temp folder.

Comment: I have a lot of rar file for this reason i dont have enough empty place  for extracting rar file

Comment: Then you have to delete old temps after extracting. Such things are known as rar bombs which could spam your pc...

Comment: okey  and also i have a problem related to extracting,  my all rar files path aaa.rar->b_folder -> c_folder -> d_folder -> z_file   due this path to  when i extract my rar files all of them seem like one folder

Answer (score 2):

Try [Nunrar](http://nunrar.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Stream%20Usage&referringTitle=Documentation). It has a streaming support which is what you're looking for. The example of counting the entries of an archive is in the link.

[Edit]

Note: You want to read and count rar file entries **without extracting** them, which is the following code does:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnrar;
using NUnrar.Archive;
using System.IO;

namespace NunrarSOF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RarArchive archive = RarArchive.Open(@"C:\Work\fileName.rar");
            int count = 0;
            //archive.Volumes.ToString();
            foreach (RarArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine(entry.FilePath);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but my Nunrar extract all of  my rar files like one folder But i  want to extarct each rar file to different folders but i cannot do it

Comment: @Sake Why, in your question, do you write 'I dont want to do extract rar files' if you now *do* want to extract them?

Comment: @Sake, do you want to use streaming or extracting?

Comment: I want to enter rar file  get folders name and files without extracting but chris579 tell "Entering rar files means you have to extract them at least info temp folder."

Comment: @Sake, did you tried the example in the link? It is clear that Nunrar supports streaming (i.e. get rar files **without extracting**) which is what you are looking for!

Comment: I tried but i couldnt add these codes to my project

Comment: @Sake, Did you add the lib package using NuGet? It's simple; Right-click on your project on the Solution Explorer -> Manage NuGet. Then search for Nunrar, add it, add the reference `using ....;` Then use the code. Try and let us know!

Comment: yes i have added , can you write which codes i have to add

Comment: string[] a = Directory.GetDirectories(entry.FilePath);                      Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Sake.Home-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\bin\Debug\ .rar files path

Comment: @Sake, `Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\foldername")`. The `GetDirectories` method should take a folder path not file path and not all the entires are folders to check use `entry.IsDirectory` property.

Comment: @ Bassem Akl  
But i want to getdirectories inside .rar files

Comment: @Sake, did you try to use the `if (entry.IsDirectory)` inside the loop and if true do your action?

Comment: yes but i dont know what i have to do add next steps

Comment: @Sake, from this point I think you should create a separate question; Add the successful code you already achieved and describe your new problem.